# .forEach is not a function node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am getting the following error and not sure why: guardian.forEach is not a function, I've Tried adding Array.for(guardian) but then I just get a large table of empty values

here is my router

```
router.get('/guardians', middleware.isAdmin, function (req, res) {
    //ShOW ADMIN ALL guardians
    
    let prom1 = User.find({isAdmin: false})
    let prom2 = User.countDocuments({isAdmin: false})
    
    Promise.all([prom1, prom2]).then(result => {
      // do your things 
      //results will be array and you can get 
      //response of prom1 in result[0]
        var guardians = JSON.stringify(result[0]);
        var allGuardians = JSON.stringify(result[1]);
        console.log(allGuardians);
        console.log(guardians);
        res.render('guardians',{currentUser: req.user, guardian:guardians, allGuardians:allGuardians });
   }).catch(err => {
//handle your error here
     console.log(`Error : ${err}`);
   })
    
});
```

and here is the view

```
<tbody>
                <% guardian.forEach(function(guardian){ %>

                <tr>
                    <td><%= guardian.name %></td>
                    <td><%= guardian.surname %></td>
                    <td><%= guardian.sex %></td>
                    <td><%= guardian.id %></td>
                    <td><%= guardian.phone %></td>
                    <td><%= guardian.email %></td>
                    <td><a href="/my_portal/<%- guardian._id%>"> View</a></td>
                </tr>

                <% }); %>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var guardians = JSON.stringify(result[0]);
> ```

...

> ```
> guardian:guardians
> ```

`guardians` is a string, not an array, so it won't have a `forEach` method.

---

Probably you want to pass `result` in, not `guardians`